# Running test suites multiple times, automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I'm using minitest and running tests against a rails backend for a gaming application.  Because the "game world" has synthesized elements that are generated according to various random distributions, I want to run the test suite repeatedly to reveal any defects that might arise as a consequence of unlikely, but possible combinations of synthesized random attributes.  (Like have it run repeatedly for several hours.)

Ideally, Id like the test suite to keep running until I stop it, or until it halts due to an discovered error scenario, at which point I will know what unlikely set of events caused it to fail.

I'm not sure how exactly to the go about this.  There doesn't seem to be a rake test option for "run multiple times" or "run till fail".

Comment: A general topic for games in general is they should only appear random. A correctly written engine can, for example, experimentally run reality backwards & retrace character movements. So minor details like testing random effects should come naturally. Another topic is some elements of play should be testable independent of the game engine's event machine. That said, the most important low-level detail you need here is a mock method on your random number generator, so it simply returns whatever number the test case needs. But proceed with your soak test, and remember to let it run every night!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a file called "run_tests_forever.rb with:

```
while true
  puts "running tests again..."
  `rake test`
end
```

(note: those are backticks to make a system call)

then run with:

```
ruby run_tests_forever.rb
```

:)

(or your equivalent requirements...)

Comment: Put that inside your Rakefile, so the `sh 'rake test' ` command can end your run on failure. (Which you want, because you are using automated tests correctly, with zero tolerance for failures.)